# How can I make custom toString for Array?

Tags: arrays, scala, scala-2.8

I want to be able to write:

```
val a = Array(1,2,3)
println(a.toString)
```

And have a meaningfull printout. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to do this:

```
scala> val a = Array(1, 2, 3)
a: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)

scala> println(a.deep)
Array(1, 2, 3)

scala>
```

Comment: How could I know this. I.e. what is yout strategy to search documentation?

Comment: You could also write a.mkString("(", ", ", ")") and have it write (1, 2, 3)

Comment: @Lukasz: I saw this some time ago on the scala-user mailing list. Didn't see the docs.